# Why 1//0.01 == 99 in Python?

Tags: python

I imagine this is a classic floating point precision question, but I am trying to wrap my head around this result, running `1//0.01` in Python 3.7.5 yields `99`.

I imagine it is an expected result, but is there any way to decide when it is safer to use `int(1/f)` rather than `1//f` ?

Comment: Yes, it is always safer int(1/f). Simply because // is the FLOOR division, and you wrongly think of it as ROUND.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This can work as expected 99.99% by always using `round()` and never `//` or `int()`. The linked question is about float comparison has nothing to do with truncation and no such easy fix.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If this were division with real numbers, `1//0.01` would be exactly 100. Since they are floating-point approximations, though, `0.01` is slightly larger than 1/100, meaning the quotient is slightly smaller than 100. It's this 99.something value that is then floored to 99.

Comment: This doesn't address the "is there a way to decide when it is safer" part.

Comment: "Safer" isn't well-defined.

Comment: Enough to completely ignore it, esp. when the OP is aware of floating point issues?

Comment: @chepner If "safer" isn't well defined, then perhaps it's better to ask for clarification :/

Comment: it's pretty clear to me that "safer" means "error not worse than a cheap pocket calculator"

Comment: @maxy - If you want to emulate the behavior of a cheap pocket calculator, you need to use decimal arithmetic (not binary floating point); see https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html.  Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @ScottHunter - While the OP is aware of the problem, it seems that he doesn't understand it.  Besides, there is no "safer" way, if you are going to use binary floating point types.  The errors are inherent, and you just need to deal with them.  (And the same is also true for decimal types; e.g. consider what happens when you compute `(1.0 / 3.0) * 3.0` using a decimal type.)

Comment: @StephenC A pocket calculator will also show that `(sqrt(2) + 0.1 - 0.1)^2` equals `2`. This is not just floating-point luck (as when using `//` in Python), but the result of doing rounding instead of truncation before diplay.

Answer (score 10):

The reasons for this outcome are like you state, and are explained in [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and many other similar Q&A.

When you know the number of decimals of numerator and denominator, a more reliable way is to multiply those numbers first so they can treated as integers, and then perform integer division on them:

So in your case `1//0.01` should be converted first to `1*100//(0.01*100)` which is 100.

In more extreme cases you can still get "unexpected" results. It might be necessary to add a `round` call to numerator and denominator before performing the integer division:

```
1 * 100000000000 // round(0.00000000001 * 100000000000)
```

But, if this is about working with fixed decimals (money, cents), then consider working with cents as *unit*, so that all arithmetic can be done as integer arithmetic, and *only* convert to/from the main monetary unit (dollar) when doing I/O.

Or alternatively, use a library for decimals, like [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), which:

> ...provides support for fast correctly-rounded decimal floating point arithmetic.

```
from decimal import Decimal
cent = Decimal(1) / Decimal(100) # Contrary to floating point, this is exactly 0.01
print (Decimal(1) // cent) # 100
```

Comment: "which obviously is 100." Not necessarily: if the .01 isn't exact, then .01 * 100 isn't as well. It must be "tuned" manually.

Answer (score 9):

What you have to take into account is that `//` is the `floor` operator and as such you should first think as if you have equal probability to fall in 100 as in 99 (*) (because the operation will be `100 ± epsilon` with `epsilon>0` provided that the chances of getting exactly 100.00..0 are extremely low.)

You can actually see the same with a minus sign,

```
>>> 1//.01
99.0
>>> -1//.01
-100.0
```

and you should be as (un)surprised.

On the other hand, `int(-1/.01)` performs first the division and then applies the `int()` in the number, which is not **[floor but a truncation towards 0](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int)**! meaning that in that case,

```
>>> 1/.01
100.0
>>> -1/.01
-100.0
```

hence,

```
>>> int(1/.01)
100
>>> int(-1/.01)
-100
```

Rounding though, would give you the YOUR expected result for this operator because again, the error is small for those figures.

(*)I am not saying that the probability is the same, I am just saying that a priori when you perform such a computation with floating arithmetic that is an estimate of what you are getting.

Answer (score 7):

Floating point numbers can't represent most decimal numbers exactly, so when you type a floating point literal you actually get an approximation of that literal. The approximation may be larger or smaller than the number you typed.

You can see the exact value of a floating point number by casting it to Decimal or Fraction.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(0.01)
Decimal('0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375')
>>> from fractions import Fractio
>>> Fraction(0.01)
Fraction(5764607523034235, 576460752303423488)
```

We can use the Fraction type to find the error caused by our inexact literal.

```
>>> float((Fraction(1)/Fraction(0.01)) - 100)
-2.0816681711721685e-15
```

We can also find out how granular double precision floating point numbers around 100 are by using nextafter from numpy.

```
>>> from numpy import nextafter
>>> nextafter(100,0)-100
-1.4210854715202004e-14
```

From this we can surmise that the nearest floating point number to `1/0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375` is in-fact exactly 100.

The difference between `1//0.01` and `int(1/0.01)` is the rounding. 1//0.01 rounds the exact result down to the next whole number in a single step. So we get a result of 99.

int(1/0.01) on the other hand rounds in two stages, first it rounds the result to the nearest double precision floating point number (which is exactly 100), then it rounds that floating point number down to the next integer (which is again exactly 100).

Comment: Calling this just *rounding* is misleading. It should be called either *truncation* or *rounding towards zero*: `int(0.9) == 0` and `int(-0.9) == 0`

Comment: It is **binary** floating point types you are talking about here.  (There are also decimal floating point types too.)

Answer (score 3):

If you execute the following

```
from decimal import *

num = Decimal(1) / Decimal(0.01)
print(num)
```

The output will be:

```
99.99999999999999791833182883
```

This is how it's internally represented,
so rounding it down `//` will give `99`

Comment: It's accurate enough to show the error in this case, but be aware that "Decimal" arithmetic is not exact either.

Comment: With `Decimal(0.01)` you are too late, the error already crept in before you call `Decimal`. I am not sure how this is an answer to the question... You must first calculate a precise 0.01 with `Decimal(1) / Decimal(100)`, like I showed in my answer.